# In what circumstance will a value be promoted to an unsigned int?

Tags: c

According to the standard [C11 p6.3.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1)

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions.58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

I'm curious in what situation will a value be promoted to an `unsigned int`? Types like `short int` definitely fit for a signed int, Even if I defined a 31bits in a struct as bit field, it still fit a signed int.

Comment: There is no default casting of integers to unsigned int, if you define a type as int it will stay an int.

Comment: @pmg I don't think there's a promotion happens in you example, you example is defined as the type of a constant in standard 6.4.4.1 Integer constants

Comment: `unsigned short` if it won't fit `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane when will `unsigned short` not fit `int`? `unsigned short int` is way shorter than `signed int` even though the later one has a signed bit.

Comment: When it's 32 bits. `unsigned short` has a *minimum* of 16 bits.

Comment: `unsigned short int is way shorter` - may be, not is.

Comment: Similarly with `long` (although there aren't integer conversions here). On my machine it is 32 bits (the minimum) but on others it is 64 bits.

Comment: so it's so called promotion but no bit width actually changed in this case?

Comment: Explained in the answer here [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). Scroll down to integer promotions.

Comment: On 8 and 16 bit systems, `unsigned short` won't fit inside `int` and will therefore get converted to `unsigned int`, which is also 16 bit and has 100% identical representation as `unsigned short`. The "conversion" is mostly academic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is when the maximum value of an integer type with rank lower then `int` is promoted. So it happens on `unsigned short`, `unsigned char` and `char` when it is `unsigned` on a platform.

When `USHRT_MAX` is greater then `INT_MAX`, then `unsigned short` is implicitly promoted to `unsigned int` type. Similar, when `UCHAR_MAX` is greater then `INT_MAX`, then  `unsigned char` is promoted to `unsigned int` type. And, when `char` on a platform is `unsigned` and `UCHAR_MAX` is greater then `INT_MAX`, the same happens to `char`.

`_Bool` will always be converted to `int`.  Although the number of bits in a `_Bool` is at least `CHAR_BIT`, the width of a `_Bool` is 1 bit, so `int` will always be able to represent all `_Bool` values . ( I am not sure if the "as restricted by the width" part of the standard applies only to bit-fields or to all types that undergo conversion. There is a comma before the "for a bit-field" part. )

P.S. The article is about C++, but I would like to recomment it: [No-one knows the type of char + char](https://blog.knatten.org/2019/05/24/no-one-knows-the-type-of-char-char/). It touches the exact problem - `char + char` can be `int` or `unsigned int`, depending on if `char` is unsigned and if `char` can hold larger values then `int`.

> Even if I defined a 31bits in a struct as bit field, it still fit a signed int.

Not always. A range of values that can be represented with a bitfield struct member that has width of 31 bits may not fit in an `signed int` variable. Simply, `signed int` may have 30 or less bits on a specific architecture. `signed int` is required to represent values *at least* between `-32767` to `+32767`.  So `2^31` may not fit into `signed int`.

Comment: It is more helpful to ignore fictional computers. On real-world computers, `char + char` is always `int`. I believe that is even true for the various exotic, obsolete DSPs with 16 bit bytes.